# SQL Server 2005 xp_sendmail error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have come across a SQL 2005 server that uses SQL mail to send emails. This setup works fine as long as the MAPI profile points to an Exchange 2003 server, but breaks when the profile points to an Exchange 2010 server. The error: xp_sendmail: failed with mail error 0x80004005

Would updating the MAPI client help fix this, or is an exchange 2010 incompatibility?

Answer (score 3):

A better option if possible would be to change out to using database mail instead of SQL mail.  This uses SMTP and takes the MAPI client out of the config.

It would require that anything that's calling xp_sendmail be changed to use sp_send_dbmail.  If you are only using this for SQL Agent emails then this is a very easy change.

Answer (score 1):

xp_sendmail should work with exchange 2010, as it is MAPI enabled and all that jazz, probably just need to update the client as you have suggested.